# Possible memory issue using an unordered_map with a vector as the object

Tags: c++, memory, vector, unordered-map

I'm writing a program that determines the prime factors of every number up to 120000. I'm trying to learn how to use unordered_map's, so that I have a map with an int as the key mapping to a vector of its prime factors.

The algorithm I've come up with involves listing all of the prime numbers below 120000, then recursively working through the products of 2 primes (2x3=6, 3x19=57 etc), then the products of 3 primes (2x2x5=20, 3x5x7=105 etc) and so on until I have a complete list.

I wrote the program to take in any maximum (not just 120000), and it works perfectly with values up to MAX_C=45000, however when I try it with MAX_C>50000, it breaks (and quite often crashes my computer.

I tried rewriting the program to avoid using unordered_maps, using a vector of my factorsAndTotal struct, but I had similar problems. I tried allocating arbitrarily large amounts of memory to the map, but to no avail.

I'm guessing this is a memory issue, but I'm not really sure, so I can't really post code fragments, sorry!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

//structs
struct factorsAndTotal
{
    vector<int> factors;
    int total;
};

//prototypes
vector<int> allPrimesLessThan(int);
void buildPrimeFactorsMap();
vector<factorsAndTotal> siftNextSet(vector<factorsAndTotal>);

//globals
int MAX_C = 45000;
vector<int> primes;
unordered_map <int, vector<int> > mapPrimeFactors;

//main
int main() 
{   
    primes = allPrimesLessThan(MAX_C);
    mapPrimeFactors.reserve(MAX_C);

    buildPrimeFactorsMap();

    cout<<mapPrimeFactors.size()<<endl;

    return 0;

}

void buildPrimeFactorsMap()
{
    vector<int> chainOfFactors;
    vector<factorsAndTotal> sifting;

    factorsAndTotal temp;

    //add primes themselves to the map
    int size = primes.size();
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        //put them in map itself and get struct ready for recursion later
        chainOfFactors.push_back(primes[i]);

        mapPrimeFactors[primes[i]] = chainOfFactors;
        temp.factors = chainOfFactors;
        temp.total = primes[i];

        sifting.push_back(temp);

        chainOfFactors.clear();
    }
    //recursion
    while (!sifting.empty())
    {
        sifting = siftNextSet(sifting);
    }

    cout<<"factors found"<<endl;
}

vector<factorsAndTotal> siftNextSet(vector<factorsAndTotal> input)
{
    int total = 0;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int size = input.size(); 
    bool finished = false;
    vector<int> chainOfFactors;
    vector<factorsAndTotal> output;
    factorsAndTotal temp;

    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        //find last factor
        while (primes[j] < input[i].factors.back()) j++;

        while (!finished)
        {
            total = input[i].total*primes[j];

            if (total > MAX_C)
            {
                finished = true;
            }
            else
            {
                chainOfFactors = input[i].factors;
                chainOfFactors.push_back(primes[j]);

                mapPrimeFactors[total] = chainOfFactors;

                temp.total = total;
                temp.factors = chainOfFactors;
                output.push_back(temp);

                chainOfFactors.clear();

                j++;
            }
        }
        finished = false;
        j=0;
    }

    return output;
}

//returns primes less than a given number
vector<int> allPrimesLessThan(int x)
{
    vector<int> findingPrimes;

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    bool isPrime;

    for (i=2; i<=x; i++)
    {
        isPrime = true;

        for (j=0; j<findingPrimes.size(); j++)
        {
            if (i%findingPrimes[j] == 0) isPrime = false;
        }

        if (isPrime) findingPrimes.push_back(i); 
    }

    cout<<"primes found"<<endl;

    return findingPrimes;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, can't find your problem. However, I would suggest a different approach: First find all appropriate primes. (I would actually suggest using [Erastothenes Sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) instead of the brute force approach you are using currently.) Then just iterate over all the number you want to factor out, and try to factor it by iterating over all the primes, trying whether they are a factor of current number. If they are, note it, if they aren't, try the next prime, if the prime is larger than the current number, break -> you already have all the prime...

Comment: factors of the number. (Or just factor out the multiples on the go and break if you reach a 1 on the running remainder.) Repeat this for all number you want to know the factors of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has little to do with the value of MAX_C you chose.  Look at this loop, along with the usage of the variable j:

```
while (primes[j] < input[i].factors.back()) 
    j++;

while (!finished)  
{
    total = input[i].total*primes[j];
```

When I run your code, j goes beyond the limit of the primes vector, since you're incrementing j in the while(!finished) loop.

The while(!finished) loop doesn't throttle how high j will go, so you need to make sure your loop either terminates or does something other than access the primes vector with an out-of-bounds value for j.

One way to ensure you don't go out of bounds:

```
while (!finished && j < primes.size() )  
{
    total = input[i].total*primes[j];
```